# Create-React-App Public Folder Subfolders

Tags: reactjs, static, create-react-app, static-files, public-folders

I have some subfolders inside the **public** folder. When I build these subfolders are put in the root of the **build** folder.

```
public/
  mySubfolder/
  favicon.ico
  index.html
  ...

build/
  mySubfolder/ 
  static/
  favicon.ico
  index.html
  ...
```

When I serve these files as static using express, serve or firebase, heroku, now... I can't access to these subfolders by url. Example: If i put one file of one of these subfolders in a iframe, I can't access to it, while if I put the path in a src attribute of a img tag it works..
Maybe the subfolders goes in conflict with routes, but I Haven't routes with a subfolder names.

My project is on github: https://github.com/Darklod/p5-sketches-react/tree/heroku?files=1
(Not Updated)

p.s. I have already read this guide: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment

Answer (score 1):

For serving the React app with express you would need something like this in your configuration:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'react')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
     res.sendFile(path.join(path.join(__dirname, 'react/index.html'));
});
```

In that example replace `react` with whatever the folder is called where your React app is located

I sadly haven't used firebase or heroku for serving React apps yet, so I sadly can't help you out with that, but I hope the Express part is solved with that

Comment: Thanks, I tried and it doesn't work. When I put the url in the browser I get 404 error and it is looking for a route, not a file D:

Comment: @Giuseppe Magazzù I forgot something in my answer. I just added it. Missed it in my code where I took the example from ;)

Comment: I have already written it this way when I tried, but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

it's been a while and I wanted to close the question. So I tried to solve it.

When I tried it I was using version 16.2.0 of react so I don't know if it also works in recent versions.

The static file management and the `__dirname` value depends on webpack and app generators like create-react-app. If you write the code from scratch you shouldn't have any problems.

However in Marco's response I have imported static files placed in the root folder (manifest.json, service-worker.js, index.html...) in this way:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```